# Select Statement Not Showing Anything

Tags: php, select

I have the following statement in my code

```
$query3="select * from students where student_name = '$referredby'";
$result3=mysql_query($query3);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result3);
if($num_rows==0){
    echo "Nobody Found";
    die();
}else{
    echo "Number Of Rows ".$num_rows;
    die();
}
```

If I do an echo for the value of the `$referredby` variable prior to running the query,  it shows me the correct value for the `$referredby` variable, and when I look at the table there is a student name that matches that value.

However when I run the program it blows right on by the if statement where I test for number of rows returned.

I'm missing something but can't seem to locate it, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, the SQL is right, so the student name is clearly wrong in one side of this. Also, <insert usual "use PDO or mysqli" statement>. Use `mysql_real_escape_string` on the `$referredby` too, since this is injectable.

Comment: try echoing the query as it runs

Comment: If you're programming a new project, it's not a good idea to do it using the old `mysql_` functions, the use of which is now discouraged.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the student name you're searching for and what is its value in the database?

Comment: @slugonamission It's probably [`Robert'; DROP TABLE students; --`](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I get the joke, but part of me still has a funny feeling the student name has a `'` in it and error reporting is off :(.

Comment: print $query; examine the output.

Comment: We are also assuming that the connection/select_db is properly set. Might be useful to insert `or die(mysql_error());` with each statement...

Comment: Also I'm guess you are check a Varchar field, so `=` will be case sensitive, you should use `LIKE` if you don't want it to be case sensitive. Otherwise 'mike' does not equal 'Mike', but 'mike' is LIKE 'Mike'.

Comment: @Pitchinnate that's wrong, MySQL varchar comparison is case-insensitive so `WHERE name = 'mike'` will find `Mike`, `MIKE`, `mIke` and so on...

Comment: OK, slug - I've already escaped the data when it came into the form
lonesome - what would you suggest instead of the old mysql_?
the student name is a nickname, in this case its ballplayer (all lower case) and it's in a varchar and it's all characters with no special characters embedded

I tried substituting LIKE for = same results,I put the or die() in still nothing.

Comment: @MrCode It actually depends on what Collation you have set. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Comment: @Hank [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) is the best alternative to `mysql_`.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing this:

```
$result3=mysql_query($query3);
```

With this

```
$result3 = mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());
```

And see if you get any MySQL errors output to your screen. If you don't then the query obviously worked and everything in the SQL is correct. Out of curiosity, what do you have the Field Type of the column storing the name set to? Text? Varchar? Blob? It SHOULDN'T matter but the more info you can give us the better.

Comment: Added it and nothing shows on the screen. I can put an echo statement above and below and they both show, but the query itself doesn't,
The field type is varchar

Comment: It's got to be something in the query statement itself, when I echo "number of rows'.$num_rows it comes back blank.

Comment: If you output the query to a string so it prints to the screen what do you get? Do you have phpmyadmin or can you connect to your server through CLI and run the query exactly as is output by your script and get the expected return?

Comment: rs,
The interesting thing is if I either echo or print the query to the screen nothing shows, I have phpmyadmin and when I run the query in the sql box, it's fine, I'm going through the code line by line to see where I've included something I shouldn't have.

Comment: Can you post more of the code that includes the variable declarations? This could helps us help you more.

Comment: @Hank did you get this figured out?